# What is a Looking Glass server?

Tags: useragent

I keep getting requests in my Apache logs from a bot with the user agent `AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: lookingglass-server)` I understand that this is a looking glass server, but I don't know what a looking glass server is. Googling seems to bring up lots of examples but no description. What is a looking glass server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia: Looking Glass servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looking_Glass_servers)

Comment: Oops. I read that but forgot that I saw it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a Google bot browsing your site. You can look up user-agents on this site:

```
http://www.botsvsbrowsers.com/
```

The bot you're refering to is listed here:

```
http://www.botsvsbrowsers.com/details/478994/index.html
```